# Option clash for package placeins

Tags: errors, packages

I am using following set of packages for my LaTeX file but I am getting following error.

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package placeins.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... \begin`
```

The packages which I am using are

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
 \smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
 \usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \sloppy
 \usepackage{placeins}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
 \usepackage{algorithmicx}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Which two packages are in conflict?

Answer (score 9):

The two packages conflicting are really one, since you load `placeins` twice, first without options and then with `section` option and this will produce the clash. Delete the one of the two lines loading the package (depending on whether you need or not the `section` option).

You could have discovered this by yourself had you typed `h` (for help) in the output console when the error appeared. After `h + return` you would get:

```
? h
The package placeins has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [section]
Adding the global options:
  ,section
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
?
```

Also, not in the question, but you are loading the obsolete `subfigure` package. Use `subfig` (which you are already loading) or `subcaption` instead.