# Write Algorithm code in IET journal template

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

[image]

i want to write Algorithm code in IET journal latex format. I am getting error as it is occured in the attached picture...Please solve this issue ..
thanks in advance

this is the Algorithm code...

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Saqib Qamar} 
\label{algo1} 
\textbf{Function} ADDING(M,W,c,k)\; 
 $i \leftarrow Mod(logM,c)$\;
\If { $j \textgreater 2^i$ $\times$
 $\lceil{\frac{k-0.5}{2}}\rceil$ }
 { $ i \leftarrow i-2^k$\;
 }
 \textbf{end if}\; \textbf{return} $Add(c^k , c^j)$\;

\textbf{end Function}\;

\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please try not to use screenshots of text. Screenshots are not searchable and it would be good to be able to find this question when searching for "Option clash for package". Also, please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118027/option-clash-for-package-placeins

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that you have loaded a package with options more than once. Look for two instances of `\usepackage[someopt]{algorithm2e}` in your preamble (where `someopt` obviously stands in for whatever options you passed). See http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-optionclash.html, which says:

> The error is a complaint about loading a package with options, more than once. LaTeX complains because it has no means of examining the options, rather than because it knows there is a problem. (You may load a package any number of times in a document’s preamble, with no options, and LaTeX will ignore every loading request after the first; but you may only supply options when you first load the package.)

If you type `h` at the error prompt, you should see more info about the clash.